# phpunit: why does this assertContains pass?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

My test should fail, but it passes:

```
public function test_getValidProviderCodes(){
    $aTest = PRIDE\Reflection::executeStaticMethodForClassName(Apps_DoctorsReports::class, "getValidProviderCodes");
    print_r($aTest);
    $this->assertContains("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", $aTest);
}
```

Output:

```
Testing started at 8:53 AM ...
PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from C:\inetpub\Intranet_Local\phpunit\phpunit.xml

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => MAYER
    [4] => MAY00
    [5] => MAYERIC
    [6] => COH00
    [7] => COH01
    [8] => POWELL
    [9] => POW00
    [10] => JOHN00
    [11] => FINO
    [12] => POL01
    [13] => NONAP
    [14] => RAYE00
    [15] => HOPS00
    [16] => CHAH00
)
 - 


Time: 1.24 seconds, Memory: 8.25Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

The value `"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` is obviously not in that array. I've used this function hundreds of times and have never seen this behavior.

(If I change `$aTest` to `[]`, the test does fail.)

---

This is another test run:

```
public function test_getValidProviderCodes(){
    $aTest = PRIDE\Reflection::executeStaticMethodForClassName(Apps_DoctorsReports::class, "getValidProviderCodes");
    $this->assertContains("S01", implode(", ", $aTest));
}
```

Output:

```
Testing started at 9:04 AM ...
PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from C:\inetpub\Intranet_Local\phpunit\phpunit.xml


Failed asserting that '0, 1, 2, M01, M03, M04, M05, N02, C01, C02, C03, C04, P01, P02, P03, P04, P05, P06, P07, R01, H01, J01, J02' contains "S01".
 C:\inetpub\Intranet_Local\phpunit\library\classes\apps\DoctorsReportsTest.php:61



Time: 1.54 seconds, Memory: 8.75Mb


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: Hi @Keith what you think about my solutions?

Comment: @Matteo It's good. I jus forgot to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi @Keith, thanks, you are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `assertContains` can check for Object Identity also (the default behaviour).  So for skip this, you need to pass an optional flag to the method. This problem is already covered [here on github](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/745).

So to make fails your test, simply pass the last optional parameter `checkForNonObjectIdentity` the value `true` as follow:

```
public function test_getValidProviderCodes(){

    $aTest =
        array(
            0,1,2,'MAYER'
        );
    print_r($aTest);
    $this->assertContains(
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        $aTest,
        'message',
        false,true,true);

}
```

with the output:

> Failed asserting that an array contains 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2017, [PHPUnit appears to have a regression bug](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2111) that causes this behavior, and for which setting the `checkForNonObjectIdentity` flag is not a solution.

You can, however, achieve `assertContains`-type behavior with strict type checking this way:

```
$this->assertTrue( in_array( $arguments, $calls, TRUE ) );
```

[The third argument to `in_array` is the `strict` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), which forces type checking when set to `TRUE`.

I use this technique in a helper function that checks if a list of args is present in a list of mock method calls. I had to change this function for strict typing after I discovered that `FALSE` and `[]` where being treated as equal, therefore causing tests to pass which should have failed.

```
protected function assertCalledWith( $mock, $method, $arguments ) {
    $calls = $mock->getCalls( $method );
    $mockName = get_class( $mock );
    $error = "Failed asserting that $mockName->$method() was called with specified args.";
    $this->assertTrue( in_array( $arguments, $calls, TRUE ), $error );
}
```